# char to string error

Tags: c#, string, char

I'm currently just 2 errors away from a working program. I'll post the line that contains error and the definition of its variable and finally the errors. Please tell me where i got wrong. Thank you.

```
    private Dictionary<string, bool[]> letterData = new Dictionary<string, bool[]>();


    public char[] mapNeurons()
    {
        char[] map = new char[this.letters.Items.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < map.Length; i++)
        {
            map[i] = '?';
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < this.letters.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            double[] input = new double[Form1.DOWNSAMPLE_HEIGHT * Form1.DOWNSAMPLE_WIDTH];
            char ch = ((string)(this.letters.Items[i]))[0];
            bool[] data = this.letterData[ch]; //line contains errors
            for (int j = 0; j < input.Length; j++)
            {
                input[j] = data[j] ? 0.5 : -0.5;
            }

            int best = this.network.Winner(input);
            map[best] = ch;
        }
        return map;
    }
```

and here are the error

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for      'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.this[string]' has some invalid arguments

Error   2   Argument '1': cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'

I used Char instead of String because if using String it will return the whole line of the string loaded, i just wants to return the first letter of the string

for example: data = A1:000001100000000110000000111000000011100000001

if use string it will return the whole line, i just wants it to return 'A'

NEW IDENTIFIED PROBLEM:
when i enter the data, i put the data into 'A1' key, which explain why im using string, so when it didnt find 'A1' because it is char, it just find 'A' thats why it returned '?', is it possible if i use string n just read the first character which is 'A' in the string line?

Comment: It's right there in the error: you can't convert from a char to a string. Maybe you need a Dictionary<char, bool[]>?

Comment: i needed the dictionary to be string for other function, only this one i need to return char instead of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert char to string, `ToString()` can be called. This is the solution for the question.

But hafizhans, was working on some program, for which he had asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904225/how-to-make-a-dictionary-that-can-hold-more-than-1-data), where he converted the `Dictionary<char, bool[]>` to `Dictionary<string, bool[]>`. Now he was storing the data from dictionary to text file something like this

```
A1:001110000111100001010100
```

Now while reading this, he only needed `A1` part, so `Split` function did the trick.
[image]

Comment: yup it works just fine if add the character to the program, the problem only occur when loading data from external file, since its string, it will read the whole line, hence no output will be displayed in the recognition box

Comment: For that you will need to modify code instead of `var ch = line.ToUpper();` do `var ch = line.Split(':')[0].ToUpper();` inside `btnLoad_Click` function.

Comment: just exactly why i needed, the .Split() function. a very much thank you again sir!

Comment: is it possible to make it read 'A1' but just display 'A' on the recognition box?

Comment: You can use `.SubString()`. Check here [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: correct me if im wrong, basically what this function do is if the string is 'A1' return 'A'? something like that?

Comment: `string str1 = "A1"; string str2 = str1.Substring(0, 1);`

Comment: so, str2 will hold 'A'? im sorry, never really good at string

Comment: not yet, do i have to put it in the load function or the last function, the mapnueron?

Comment: in mapNeurons, instead of `map[best] = ch;` do `map[best] = ch.Substring(0, 1);`

Comment: for some reason, letter 'M' and 'W' cannot be displayed. any idea why?

Comment: nvm, its because the box is too small

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to add items to the dictionary with the [Add() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx).

Secondly, your dictionary's key is a string, so you need to use a string as the index ... you can get the string representation of a char by calling `ToString()` on the char instance.

```
char ch = 'x';

private Dictionary<string, bool[]> letterData = new Dictionary<string, bool[]>();
letterData.Add(ch.ToString(), new []{true, false});

bool[] data = this.letterData[ch.ToString()];
```

Or change the index to char:

```
char ch = 'x';

private Dictionary<char, bool[]> letterData = new Dictionary<char, bool[]>();
letterData.Add(ch, new []{true, false});

bool[] data = this.letterData[ch];
```

Comment: actually this only a small part of the program, i just thought some modification could be made to those line to solve the error

Answer (score 2):

```
bool[] data = this.letterData[ch.ToString()];
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED

Try this:

```
if(this.letterData.ContainsKey(ch.ToString()))
    bool[] data = this.letterData[ch.ToString()];
```

or

```
if(this.letterData.ContainsKey(ch.ToString()))
    bool[] data = this.letterData[ch+""];
```

Comment: when i do both of this line sir, the program stop at certain point saying 'the given key was not present in dictionary'

Comment: your code works well sir without error, unfortunately it just return '?' everytime. i think i know why because when i enter the data, i put the data into 'A1' key, which explain why im using string, so when it didnt find 'A1' because it is char, it just find 'A' thats why it returned '?', is it possible if i use string n just read the first character which is 'A' in the string line?

Answer (score 0):

How about changing to:

```
string sCh = ch.ToString();
bool[] data = null;
if (this.letterDate.ContainsKey(sCh)
{
   data = this.letterData[sCh];
}
```

In addition, you may want consider changing the key on the dictionary to be Char instead.

Comment: the program stop at certain point saying 'the given key was not present in dictionary'

Comment: Ok, you need to check to see if the dictionary `ContainsKey` prior to accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

the variable `ch` is most likely a char you have to use a string instead

Comment: i have to use char cause if i use string it will read the whole line, is there a way to just read the first letter of the string line?

Comment: @hafizhans: Do you mean that you want to find items in the dictionary that begin with that letter? It doesn't work like that.

Comment: i did enter the 'A1' key into the dictionary for that particular data

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
char charString = 'a';
if (letterData.ContainsKey(charString.ToString()))
{
    // Found
}
```